# Анимация заливки термометра svg + jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg, svg-animation

[image: Термометр]

Хочу сделать свг градусник и чтобы при нажатии на чекбоксы, заливка проводилась плавно снизу вверх, включая деления термометра(следовательно когда галочки будут снимать то заливка будет так же плавно спускаться). Интересует как сделать такую заливку и прикрутить jquery для этого. (Чекбоксы работают по принципу toogleClass("check")).

Вот что я смог напортачить в Jquery

```
$(".analysis-li").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("check");
    var firstStop = document.getElementById('F1gst1');
    percentage = '10%'; firstStop.setAttribute('offset',percentage);
});
```

Нужно сделать чтобы при каждом классе check процент увеличивался, а при убирание этого класса, он опять уменьшался. Ниже html и css

```
<li class="analysis-li"></li>
<li class="analysis-li"></li>
<li class="analysis-li"></li>
<li class="list analysis-li"></li>
<li class="list analysis-li"></li>
<li class="analysis-li"></li>

li.analysis-li 
    margin-bottom: 54px
    position: relative
    padding-left: 20px
    cursor: pointer

    &::before
        position: absolute
        content: ''
        width: 34px
        height: 34px
        left: -34px
        bottom: 3px
        border: #d3ad4b solid 3px
        background-color: transparent
        cursor: pointer
        background-image: url(../img/check.png) 
        background-repeat: no-repeat
        background-position: center
        background-size: 0

    &.check::before
        background-size: 30px

    &:hover::before
        border-color: #c29846
        transition: .3s
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JQyKRL

Скинул сам градусник

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56787001/7394871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался с помощью установки градиента. Не забудьте удалить тэг style в svg если он у вас есть. Градиент вставляется после открывающего тега svg перед path.

```
<linearGradient y2="0%" x2="0%" y1="100%" x1="0%" id="F1g"><stop stop-color="#00FF00" offset="0%" id="F1gst1"/><stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="0%" id="F1gst2"/></linearGradient>
```

Потом при помощи offset добился заливки в процентах. Потом идет сравнивание количество элементов и количество выбранных элементов. И после этого задается результат.

```
var firstStop = document.getElementById('F1gst1');
percentage = '0%';
var CountAllCheckboxes = $('.analysis-li').length;
var CountChecked = 0;

$(".analysis-li").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("check");

    CountChecked = $('.analysis-li.check').length;
    percentage = ((CountChecked / CountAllCheckboxes) * 100)+'%';
    firstStop.setAttribute('offset',percentage);
});
```

Решение с плавной анимацией https://stackoverflow.com/a/56836400/11707220

Answer (score 5):

Вот собрал что-то подобное, извиняйте уж без жуквери, изменил верстку на программную, если это не надо можно скопировать готовый `html` из сниппета через отладчик

```js
let path = (y, d, extra) => `<path d="${d}" transform="translate(0,${y})" ${extra||''}></path>`
let multi = (count, html) => Array(count).fill(0).map((e, i) => html(i)).join('');
let toggle = el => el.classList.toggle('on') | 
   rect.setAttribute('y', 14.6*(7-document.querySelectorAll("path.on").length)+8)
scale.innerHTML = multi(10, i => path(i*10, 'M60,10h10M65,12h5M65,14h5M65,16h5M65,18h5'));
checks.innerHTML = multi(7, i => path(i*12, 'M10,10v8h8v-8z', 'class="on" onclick="toggle(this)"') +
                                 path(i*12, 'M12,14l2.2,2l2.2,-4'))
```

```css
g#scale path { 
  stroke: white; 
  stroke-width: 0.7; 
}

#checks { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 20px; 
  left: 20px; 
}

#checks path {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
  stroke: #f5b53a;
  cursor:pointer;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
}

#checks path.on + path {
  opacity:1;
}

#checks path:nth-child(2n) {
 opacity: 0;
 pointer-events: none;
 transition: 0.5s;
 stroke: white;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 135 135" height="90vh" style="background-color:purple">
  <defs><mask id="termometer">
    <path d="M80,10v100" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
    <circle r="10" cy="120" cx="80" fill="white"></circle>
    <g id="scale"></g>
  </mask></defs>
  <rect width="130" height="130" mask="url(#termometer)" fill="white"></rect>
  <rect id="rect" style="transition:1s" y="8" width="130" height="130" 
        mask="url(#termometer)" fill="#f5b53a"></rect>
  <g id="checks"></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: А почему умножить на 18 ммм ?

Comment: @MaximLensky просто подобрал коэффициент (весь диапазон делить на 7)

Comment: Примерно понял как сделать это у себя, но стал вопрос по поводу path и как так-же разделять svg на категории для заливки?

Comment: @Александр я не понял вопрос

Comment: А если у меня есть <li class="analysis-li" > В котором есть псевдоэлемент before который и отвечает за создание чексбоксов
`код`
border: #d3ad4b solid 3px
cursor: pointer
background-image: url(../img/check.png) 
background-repeat: no-repeat
background-size: 0

`код`
.check:before
background-size 30px
`код` для Jquery
$(".analysis-li").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("check");
    var firstStop = document.getElementById('F1gst1');
    percentage = '11%'; firstStop.setAttribute('offset',percentage);
});

Comment: @Александр Вам нужно искать выбраные инпуты и навешивать слушатель по Вашему селектору `.checked`, добавьте разментку в вопрос

Comment: Кстати а почему при  снятии нижней галочки не отменяются верхнии? это как бы не правильно ... ммм ?

Comment: @MaximLensky бог его знает как правильно, автор указал про галочки - если думать про именно температуру - логичнее радио кнопки.

Answer (score 3):

В общем вот так примерно

> Смотреть на полный экран

```js
let move = cb => rect.setAttribute('y', 400 - cb.textContent*50)

document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox')
        .forEach(cb => cb.addEventListener('click', e => move(cb)))
```

```css
* {
  user-select: none;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.text {
  font-size: 20px;
  fill: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

.svg-event {
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 500px;
}

.panel div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  margin: 18px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-weight: 900;
}

#rect {
  transition: 0.68s cubic-bezier(0.05, 1.06, 0.71, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-event">
  <svg width="800px" height="600px">
        <mask id="mask">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" fill="white"/>
            <circle  cx="450" cy="450" r="50" />
            <rect x="435.8" y="50" width="30" height="360" rx="14" />
            <g transform="translate(350,30)">
            <g id="line">
                <rect  width="100" height="5" x="-45" y="20"/>
                <rect  width="40" height="5" x="15" y="30"/>
                <rect  width="40" height="5" x="15" y="40"/>
                <rect  width="40" height="5" x="15" y="50"/>
                <rect  width="40" height="5" x="15" y="60"/>
            </g>
                <use xlink:href="#line" y="50" />
                <use xlink:href="#line" y="100" />
                <use xlink:href="#line" y="150" />
                <use xlink:href="#line" y="200" />
                <use xlink:href="#line" y="250" />
                <use xlink:href="#line" y="300" />
            </g>
       </mask>

       <rect id="rect" width="800" height="600" fill="orange" y="400"/>
       <rect width="800" height="600" fill="#8E7CFF" mask="url(#mask)"/>

       <g transform="translate(220,40)">
           <text class="text" x="100" y="0">7</text>
           <text class="text" x="100" y="50">6</text>
           <text class="text" x="100" y="100">5</text>
           <text class="text" x="100" y="150">4</text>
           <text class="text" x="100" y="200">3</text>
           <text class="text" x="100" y="250">2</text>
           <text class="text" x="100" y="300">1</text>
       </g>
       <g>
           <text class="text" x="500" y="70">
               Высокая темпиратура
           </text>
           <text class="text" x="500" y="210">
                Средняя темпиратура
            </text>
            <text class="text" x="500" y="360">
                Низкая темпиратура
            </text>
       </g>
    </svg>
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="checkbox" tabindex="7">7</div>
    <div class="checkbox" tabindex="6">6</div>
    <div class="checkbox" tabindex="5">5</div>
    <div class="checkbox" tabindex="4">4</div>
    <div class="checkbox" tabindex="3">3</div>
    <div class="checkbox" tabindex="2">2</div>
    <div class="checkbox" tabindex="1">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: я думал сделать через use, но почему то не стал, наверное чтобы тебе можно было поставить плюс

Comment: Тебе не показалось, но я частенько не уделяю внимания деталям, которые на прямую к вопросу не относятся, иначе получается что автору не останется простора для творчества :)

Comment: ну да, это все таки не фриланс биржа =), когда хочется и интересно - делаю, а рутина ни к чему

Comment: поправил твой ответ

Comment: @StrangerintheQ согласен Вы настоящий злодей с es6 ...

Comment: @MaximLensky отличный ответ. А пояснения, хоть краткие может добавишь? Плюс тебе и `Stranger in the Q`

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  я руку сломал и мне одной рукой писать сложновато

Comment: @MaximLensky О, Макс, сочувствую, выздоравливай

Answer (score 2):

### Решение jQuery

Вот как бы я это сделал. Для анимации градиента я использую `requestAnimationFrame`. Я анимирую второе смещение `stop` между 10% и 100%, но вы можете выбрать нужные значения.

Пожалуйста, прочитайте комментарии в коде.

```js
 // Второй stop градиента
 let laststop = document.getElementById('F1gst2');
 // переменная, используемая для переключения анимации
 let n = 0;
 // целевое значение атрибута смещения
 let target;
 // фактическое значение атрибута смещения (offset)
 let val = 10;
 //идентификатор кадра анимации запроса
 let rid = null;

$(".analysis-li").click(function(){
   
   n++;
   // установить целевое значение
   if(n%2 == 1){
     target = 100; 
   }else{target = 10}
    // если есть анимация, то  остановить  
    if(rid){cancelAnimationFrame(rid); rid="null"}
    // вызвать функцию кадра
    frame()      
});


function frame(){
  rid = requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  //расстояние между значением и целевым значением
  dist = target - val;
  //Увеличить значение
  val += dist/10;
  // установить значение offset
  laststop.setAttributeNS(null,"offset",`${val}%`)
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:30px}
path{stroke:black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="analysis-li">click here</p>
<svg class="thermometr" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 44.3 333.8" >
                <linearGradient y2="0%" x2="0%" y1="100%" x1="0%" id="F1g">
                  <stop stop-color="#00FF00" offset="0%" id="F1gst1"/>
                  <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="10%" id="F1gst2"/>
                </linearGradient>
                <path fill="url(#F1g)" class="st0" d="M30.5 297.5V4.6c0-2.5-2.1-4.6-4.6-4.6-2.5 0-4.6 2.1-4.6 4.6v292.9c-7.9 2-13.8 9.2-13.8 17.8 0 10.2 8.2 18.4 18.4 18.4s18.4-8.2 18.4-18.4c0-8.5-5.9-15.7-13.8-17.8"/>
  <path fill="url(#F1g)" class="st0"  d="M9 290.2h7.5v.5H9zM9 284.3h7.5v.6H9zM9 278.4h7.5v.5H9zM9 272.5h7.5v.6H9zM0 266.6h16.5v.6H0zM9 260.7h7.5v.5H9zM9 254.8h7.5v.6H9zM9 248.9h7.5v.5H9zM9 243h7.5v.6H9zM0 237.1h16.5v.6H0zM9 231.3h7.5v.5H9zM9 225.4h7.5v.6H9zM9 219.5h7.5v.6H9zM9 213.6h7.5v.6H9zM0 207.7h16.5v.6H0zM9 201.8h7.5v.6H9zM9 195.9h7.5v.6H9zM9 190h7.5v.6H9zM9 184.1h7.5v.5H9zM0 178.2h16.5v.6H0zM9 172.3h7.5v.6H9zM9 166.4h7.5v.5H9zM9 160.5h7.5v.6H9zM9 154.7h7.5v.6H9zM0 148.8h16.5v.6H0zM9 142.9h7.5v.6H9zM9 137h7.5v.5H9zM9 131.1h7.5v.5H9zM9 125.2h7.5v.6H9zM0 119.3h16.5v.5H0zM9 113.4h7.5v.6H9zM9 107.5h7.5v.6H9zM9 101.6h7.5v.5H9zM9 95.7h7.5v.6H9zM0 89.8h16.5v.6H0zM9 83.9h7.5v.6H9zM9 78.1h7.5v.6H9zM9 72.2h7.5v.6H9zM9 66.3h7.5v.6H9zM0 60.4h16.5v.6H0zM9 54.8h7.5v.6H9zM9 48.9h7.5v.6H9zM9 43h7.5v.5H9zM9 37.1h7.5v.6H9zM0 31.2h16.5v.5H0zM9 26h7.5v.6H9zM9 20.1h7.5v.5H9zM9 14.2h7.5v.6H9zM9 8.3h7.5v.6H9zM0 2.4h16.5V3H0z"/>
    </svg>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56790156/7394871): @enxaneta